# Weird "attempt call field "drawers"(a table value)" error

Tags: lua, compiler-errors, love2d

I was working on this project about a year ago. I came back to it and now it throws an error when I run it the error is "attempt call field "drawers"(a table value)".

This is where the drawers field is

```
local Renderer = {}

local num_of_layers = 2
local insert = table.insert
local remove = table.remove


function Renderer:create()
    local render = {}

    render.drawers = {}
    for i  = 0, num_of_layers do
        render.drawers[i] = {}
    end

    function render:addRenderer(obj, layer)
        local l = layer or 0
        insert(self.drawers(l), i, obj)
    end

    return render
end

return Renderer
```

This is where it is being called

```
local tlm = {}

function tlm:load()
     renderer:addRenderer(self)
     gameloop:addLoop(self)
end
```

Comment: It's a bit confusing with the uppercase `Renderer` and the lowercase `renderer`, and the function `Renderer:create` doesn't actually have an end, from our point of view. Could you make the code a little clearer?

Comment: Also, spotted the error. `drawers` is actually a table containing some tables, but you're calling it passing `l` as an argument from `renderer:addRenderer`. Again, I can't understand what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct:

```
insert(self.drawers(l), obj)
```

`self.drawers` is not a function but a table. therefor a function call like `self.drawers(1)` results in an error.

If you wanted to insert an element to the table self.drawers at index l using Luas standard functions you should call:

```
table.insert(self.drawers, i, obj)
```

If you want to replace the value at index l you can simply write `self.drawers[l] = obj`

http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.insert